# react-native app iphone X heats up extensively

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, iphone-x

I have a react-native app that works flawlessly on most of the iPhone devices, but recently after rolling it out to a vast share of users I started getting alot of complaints that the iPhone X heats up while using the react-native app.

Has anyone ever experienced the same as I cannot find the root cause of this issue.

Thanks!